# SseBroadcaster kotlin/quarkus - throws nullpointer exception on broadcast if a registered eventsink is closed

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, server-sent-events

I'm trying to incorporate Server Sent Events (SSE) in a small application of mine where I want to utilize the broadcast functionality, however i've stumpled upon an issue I cannot seem to resolve. I've searched the world wide web for further information, but no examples or documentation seems to cover the cleanup/error handling.

Whenever I connect/register with multiple clients(SseEventSink) to my broadcaster and broadcast a message all the clients receive the message, but if i close the connection of one of the first clients connected and broadcast after. I get a nullpointer thrown by the broadcaster.broadcast function.

This abrupts the broadcast and the eventsinks later in the list would receive the message. All the eventsinks up until the nullpointer will receive the message.

To illustrate an example:

**Client 1:** connects

**Client 2:** connects

**Client 3:** connects

**Server:** Broadcasts (All clients receive a message)

**Client 2:** closes it's connection

**Server:** Broadcasts again (Throws nullpointer)

**Client 1:** receives message

**Client 2:** Closed

**Client 3:** Does not receive message because of nullpointer.

**Code:**

**Model**

```
package your.packagename.models

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.util.*

data class Tweet (
    @JsonProperty("uuid")
    val uuid: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    @JsonProperty("text")
    val text: String,
    @JsonProperty("time")
    val time: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
)
```

**Service**

```
package your.packagename.services

import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Context
import jakarta.ws.rs.sse.OutboundSseEvent
import jakarta.ws.rs.sse.Sse
import jakarta.ws.rs.sse.SseBroadcaster
import jakarta.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink

@ApplicationScoped
class EventService(@Context private val sse: Sse) {

private val broadcaster: SseBroadcaster = sse.newBroadcaster()

init {
    this.broadcaster.onClose { eventSink ->
        println("Closing event stream: $eventSink")
        if(!eventSink.isClosed) {
            eventSink.close()
        }
    }
    this.broadcaster.onError { eventSink: SseEventSink, throwable: Throwable ->
        println("${throwable.message}: $eventSink")
        if(!eventSink.isClosed) {
            eventSink.close()
        }
    }
}

fun createEvent(message: String): OutboundSseEvent {
    return sse.newEvent(message)
}

fun register(sseEventSink: SseEventSink) {
    println("Context event service: Added new event sink $sseEventSink")
    this.broadcaster.register(sseEventSink)
}

fun broadcast(sseEvent: OutboundSseEvent) {
    println("Context event service: publishing new message ${sseEvent.data}")
    this.broadcaster.broadcast(sseEvent)
}

}
```

**Controller:**

```
package your.packagename.integrations.exposed.rest.controllers

import your.packagename.models.Tweet
import your.packagename.services.EventService
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.Default
import jakarta.inject.Inject
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Context
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import jakarta.ws.rs.sse.Sse
import jakarta.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import kotlin.random.Random


@Path("v1/broadcast")
class BroadcastController {

@Inject
@field: Default
lateinit var eventService: EventService

@GET
@Path("/stream")
@Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
fun getData(@Context sse: Sse, @Context sseEventSink: SseEventSink) {
    sseEventSink.use { // .use is like try with ressource (Autoclosable) in java.
        var lastEventId = 0
        while (lastEventId < 5) {
            Thread.sleep(500)
            val tweet = Tweet(text = "123", time = ZonedDateTime.now())

            val sseEvent = sse.newEventBuilder()
                .id(lastEventId.toString())
                .name("message")
                .mediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .data(tweet)
                .reconnectDelay(3000)
                .comment("new message")
                .build()
            sseEventSink.send(sseEvent);
            lastEventId++
        }
    }
}

@GET
@Path("/tweet")
fun getTweet(): Tweet {
    return Tweet(text = "Test tweet", time = ZonedDateTime.now())
}

@GET
@Path("/subscribe")
@Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
fun subscribeContext(@Context sseEventSink: SseEventSink) {
    eventService.register(sseEventSink);
}

@POST
@Path("/publish")
fun publishContext(message: String) {
    val randomNum = Random.nextInt(2)
    val event = if (randomNum % 2 == 0)
        eventService.createEvent(message)
    else
        eventService.createEvent(
            Tweet(text = "Test tweet", time = ZonedDateTime.now()).toString()
        )
    eventService.broadcast(event)
}
}
```

I'd like to do some sort of cleanup if a connection closes on purpose or by error. However The broadcaster doesn't seem to have any access to the eventsinks so I can manually close/remove them.

All I can find is the .onClose and onError eventListeners you can add, which doesn't let me access the list of registered eventsinks.

All wise knowledge and ideas are appreciated.

Thank you in advance